# How to calculate the ascending and descending node, as well as the true anomaly

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-elements

I have the argument of perihelion, semi-major axis, eccentricity, inclination and mass. I have tried to look this up but get conflicting answers. Any help would be appreciated.

(Edit)
One physics forum gave me this formula,

$$r = a  \frac{1 - e^2}{1 + e  \cos \theta}$$

Reference: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/position-of-ascending-and-descending-nodes.534665/
where to my understanding, theta is the true anomaly, this forum also states to minus the argument of perihelion from 360 to get my true anomaly value.

Another stated to do $2 \pi$ - arg of perihelion, though I think this Doesnt apply as it is a Keplerian orbit.

Comment: Please edit your question to show information on the conflicting answers and how far you have gotten.

Comment: All the information you have provided is completely independent of longitude of the ascending node, or of the true anomaly. If all you have is the  argument of perihelion, semi-major-axis, eccentricity, inclination, and mass of the central body, _any_ value of Longitude of the ascending node or of the True Anomaly could be valid values.